# How to check permission support for device?

Tags: android, google-play, user-permissions, uses-feature

My application do not show in some devices when trying to download via Google Play.From googling I understood that it is due to `uses-permission`  and we can it by `uses-feature`

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
```

I want to fix this issue.So how can i check which of these `uses-permission` supports the current device and enable the supported permissions?

Also, How can we check the these permission related non listing issue locally with out uploading to google play?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'd be amazed if someone could provide a solution for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by this?I want to set permissions  required="false" in manifest and while at running check for permission support.If it supports enable it .

Comment: What I meant was: play store looks through the permissions that your app requires. It does not inform your app what it is looking for. I'm still hoping that someone will find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about permissions. All features that you used in your application cannot be supported by all android devices. Google Play automaticly sets up your supported device list by checking your application features. You can see that list in your google play accaount.

Permissions are for using device features like GPS, Camera etc..

For example in order to use GPS you need to add this line to your Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is the  details for permissions

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Ok.Is it possible to check these feature issues locally ie,without uploading to google play?

Comment: As far as i know you cannot check the supported device list without uploading it to Google Play. However you can check for the link i posted to understand in which condition you need to set user permissions. Just keep this in mind for all the device features you used you need to set permissions